# MSMQ BodyType Integer Allocation

Tags: properties, msmq, message-queue

I couldn't find anything about the BodyType-Property (beside the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.messaging.message.bodytype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), especially nothing about the meaning of each integer.
So I created messages with BodyTypes = 0...1000 and wrote down the result into an Excel-sheet.
I hope this is helpful for someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: MSMQ BodyType Integer Allocation]

Maybe there are even more BodyTypes and someone could add them

Comment: I read somewhere that if a Message has a BodyType of `VT_EMPTY` but the Body has content, then it's parsed as a `byte[]` exactly as if it were of type `VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1`

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question and answer are two years old, it sometimes helps to dig through the C++ documentation when dealing with obscure MS API's. This is no exception.

[PROPID_M_BODY_TYPE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703268(v=vs.85).aspx)

Describes the body types, and what the body should contain.

What continues to be unclear to me is weather these values should have custom values when creating a custom format handler.