# Windows message queue always inserts with a BodyType of 0?

Tags: msmq

My new project at work requires me to know about MSMQ. I'm currently trying to figure out how to parse the `Body` of a message. Problem is, every message I enter has a `BodyType` of `0`. I have only one Public Queue on my computer and I fill it with test data with this C#

```
using System;
using System.Messaging;

namespace Sandbox {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            MessageQueue q = MessageQueue.GetPublicQueuesByMachine(Environment.MachineName)[0];

            q.Purge();

            Person me = new Person();
            me.Name = "Corey Ogburn";
            me.Number = 25;

            q.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(String), typeof(Person) });

            q.Send(1);
            q.Send("One");

            q.Send(2);
            q.Send("Two");

            q.Send(3);
            q.Send("Three");

            q.Send(me);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything goes smooth and in Computer Management, I can see that the 7 messages are in there, I can view their bodies and verify that all of them are going in correctly (as XML entries).

However, when I go to read these messages, all of them have a `BodyType` of `0`

```
public void AllMessages(String server, String queue) {
    MessageQueueCriteria crit = new MessageQueueCriteria();
    crit.MachineName = server;
    crit.Label = queue;
    using (MessageQueueEnumerator e = MessageQueue.GetMessageQueueEnumerator(crit)) {
        if (e.MoveNext()) {
            e.Current.MessageReadPropertyFilter = new MessagePropertyFilter();
            e.Current.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll();
            foreach (Message m in e.Current.GetAllMessages()) {
                // Here, m.BodyType is always 0
            }
        }
        e.Close();
    }
}
```

I keep reading that [this field should be set for me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.messaging.message.bodytype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I believe I'm reading the Messages correctly, so I think I must be inserting them wrong. Insertion is so simple that I'm not sure how I could do it differently. According to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134862/msmq-bodytype-integer-allocation), I should be getting BodyTypes of 3 for a signed int, 30 or 31 for my strings, and 68 or 69 for my object. At the very least, if MSMQ only sees them as strings, then they should all be 30 or 31. I can't explain why I'm getting 0. What can I do to properly set these numbers as the BodyType?

EDIT: It seems that even if I set the BodyType when storing a message, it still comes out as 0 when I go to read it. Adding this code:

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.Body = me;
msg.BodyType = 69;
q.Send(msg);
```

It adds my custom object to the queue but the message looks exactly like the previous `q.Send(me)`.

Windows 7 which I believe is MSMQ 4. It's a non-transactional queue, no auth or security.

Comment: BodyType 69 - VT_STORED_OBJECT - is used for [a persistent serialized object whose format is the output of a call to OleSave using IPersistStorage.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701459(v=vs.85).aspx) which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: I'm writing an administrative dashboard to watch various MSMQs. I would like to be able to not request the Body but at least get some insight into what the body contains when I query remote servers. I know that it won't tell me anything about what type of object is stored, but I hope to count how many objects there are as well as strings, ints, and binary too. Currently, no matter what I insert, MSMQ always indicates it's a byte[].

Comment: Perhaps the formatter is setting it, have you tried without it?

Comment: Yeah. No formatted results in the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use BinaryMessageFormatter. Regardless, whether you are reading/writing it's best to set the Formatter, so you're 100% sure you can de/serialize on both ends.

You can also right-click 'My Computer' > Manage > Services and Applications > Message Queueing

There you will be able to see the body of the message, and double-check your logic.