# Fetching Data of a private msmq using GetAllMessages method of MessageQueue class

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, system.messaging

I am trying to fetch all the messages of a private queue by using this code and want to write these messages in XML file .When I was unsuccessful to do that then I try this code.

```
string queuePath = ".\\private$\\test";
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);

Message[] messages = queue.GetAllMessages();
        foreach (Message msg in messages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.Body);
        }
```

I found this code from Microsoft Official website but I am getting This error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot find a formatter capable of reading this message.

Please suggest me the solution

Comment: Taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/657700/7450780)?

Comment: But I can't  fix the Data Type of the message of a queue. can you suggest me solution which is not Type dependent of message

Comment: Can anyone help me in this out that we can read and write messages of a queue without knowing that which data type value it is containing.

Comment: For more clarification we can understand it like that can we implement a global process to read  messages from queue without be dependent on its datatype.